# MySQL Connector/Python 1.0.7 on OSX 10.8 not getting a cursor

Tags: mysql, python

Here's a skeleton of my Python code:

```
import mysql.connector
sql = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='pwd',
      host='127.0.0.1', database='my_db')

cursor = sql.cursor()
```

Yields this mysterious error message:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pyscript_v2.py", line 36, in 
cursor = sql.cursor()
file "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 1063, in cursor raise errors.OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.**

My Google-fu is failing to dig anything up, am I missing something in setting up my MySQL DB connection in Python?

I'm running Python 2.7.2 on OS X 10.8.2, and am using MySQL Connector/Python 1.0.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following link has explanation and possible solution.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67649

Comment: Thank you! I went with MySQLdb in the end, but will follow up and see if that caused my error.